# Rails 5 using Kaminari twice on same page renders full page in partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, kaminari

a controller action has two sets of data (originating form the same class, but drawn from different queries

```
    @usercontents = Usercontent.where(contenttype_id > ?, 1).page params[:page]
    @points = Usercontent.where(contenttype_id = ? ', 1]).page params[:page]
```

The views has partials who in turn invoke their own partials

```
    <%= render 'points' %>
```

and

```
    <%= render 'contents' %>
```

_contents.html.erb partial

```
<%= paginate @usercontents, remote: true, previous_label: t('navigate.previous'), next_label: t('navigate.next'), params: {anchor: 'panel3'} %>

<div id=usercontents class='tableize'>
  <%= render partial: 'usercontents/usercontent', collection: @usercontents %>
</div>
```

_points_html.erb partial

```
<%= paginate @points, remote: true, previous_label: t('navigate.previous'), next_label: t('navigate.next'), params: {anchor: 'panel2'} %>

<div id=points class='tableize'>
  <%= render partial: 'point', collection: @points %>
</div>
```

As the view alludes to, the pagination collections are in seperate tabulations of the page.
The end result is that pages do get paginated, but the call has three problems:

1. Instead of having a XHR call for just the collection, all assets are being invoked
2. rendering is not occuring for just the partial but the whole page (including stringified javascript!)
3. the pagination rendering is being placed **after** the  partial, not in substitution of.  calling another page just adds the new page to the end of previous block.

What is incorrect in this setup?